# Session data in SignalR: Where to store them?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Let's assume that I have a game which uses SignalR to share information between clients. In my Hub class I have a method called "joinGame()" which is called when some client wants to join. I need to add his ID to some array, to know that he has already joined the game. It doesn't need to be in database, because I need this information only during this session.

```
public class GameHub : Hub
{
    public List<int> Players = new List<int>();

    public void joinGame(int id) //player updates his position
    {
         Clients.All.newPlayer(id);
         Players.Add(id);
    }
}
```

This code won't work, because "Players" variable seems to be cleared every time I call "joinGame()" function.

How can I do it properly?

Comment: Why use a own ID, use the connection ID instead

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups):

```
public async Task JoinGame(int id)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, id);
    Clients.All.newPlayer(id);
}
```

Comment: As I see in documentation, Groups are the object that can only store information about users. But what if I wanted to store some other data too? Like: score of each player, or time of beginning game?

Comment: and can I check if player is already added to Group? To prevent adding the same player multiple times?

Comment: You can also use a static variable containing users currently connected and override OnConnected method, you can also store anything else you want along with the connection ids  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692152/5220681