# Check Client connection from hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

Currently i'm working on AspnetCore project using Signalr and i'm facing this problem:
-Client connect to hub, and call function A()
-Hub Run A() but it blocks any other call from that client
-Client Call Function B() to Stop function A() but doesn't stop
I read that Signalr treat calls sequentially, so i tried to call disconnect from client but the hub still still believe that he's connected(while the hub is Running A())
so my question is: Is there a way to check if the client is still connected from the hub ? like a ping or something?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignalR - Checking if a user is still connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692069/signalr-checking-if-a-user-is-still-connected)

Comment: Hello. Can you provide some code of your hub? And the startup?

Comment: @Selim Yıldız , as i said , the OnConnect and On Disconnect evetns of the hub won't be fired because the Function A() is running

Comment: @Kiril1512 Basic Startup & Hub, and image Function A() to be an infinit loop that stops when a B() is called

Comment: Then you are speaking about cancellationtoken behaviour.

Comment: @Kiril1512 , any more explications please ?

Comment: @LeoCruz see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a cancellationtoken behaviour. You want to client pass a cancellationtoken and that is what you are trying to archive when you calling the method B().

But this behaviour is not supported in SignalR as you can read [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2241) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11542).

Comment: thanks for the asnwer, so there is nothing a i can do about it ?

Comment: Maybe you can create another question if it is possible to do something different to cancel the request.