# Is there a way to Authenticate users who connect to Azure SignalR?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I am really struggling to understand on how to implement this. I have an Azure SignalR service running. I have an Azure Function setup. I have a Web API.

The Web API fires a HTTP POST to the Azure Function and using a HTTPTrigger it then sends out (broadcasts) to all users who are connected to the Azure SignalR service. Great!

Now I have a problem, the Web API must send messages only to a specific user for each HTTP POST. Obviously this would me the user would need to authenticate somehow when they connect to (or "Negotiate") with Azure SignalR.

Truth be told, I know how to authenticate users when I have a self-hosted SignalR application. Done this prior with bearer token authentication whenever users connected to the Hub for SignalR. However, that was self-hosted SignalR. I am now using Azure SignalR hosted on Azure.

Also I need to say that the Negotatiate and all methods that the clients for the Azure SignalR listen to are Azure Functions.

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfo
        (HubName = "notifications")] //, UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}"
        SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        // connectionInfo contains an access key token with a name identifier claim set to the authenticated user
        return connectionInfo;
    }

    [FunctionName("PlacedOrderNotification")]
    public static async Task Placed(
    [QueueTrigger("new-order-notifications")] OrderPlacement orderPlacement,
    [SignalR(HubName = "notifications")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
    ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Sending notification for {orderPlacement.CustomerName}");

            await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target = "productOrdered",
                    Arguments = new[] { orderPlacement }
                });
        }
```

I want to take my bearer token authentication and place it within Azure SignalR somehow.

Now the million dollar question... how on earth do I go about doing that? Can I re-use my Bearer Auth code used for a self hosted SignalR service and integrate it into my architecture somehow?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The normal use process should be the scenario described below.**

> The Web API fires a HTTP POST to the Azure Function and using a HTTPTrigger it then sends out (broadcasts) to all users who are connected to the Azure SignalR service. Great!

From your description, Web API send a post which body contains json data, like:

```
{
  "orderid": "0001",
  "status" : "created",
  "userid" : "Jason",
  ......
}
```

Then your `function app` needs to process this order information and find out who needs to push to receive this message.

[**Suggestion, you can integrate signlar with function app.**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/tree/master/samples/chat-with-custom-auth/csharp/FunctionApp)

According to business information and requirements, push order information to designated users.

[1. SignalR - Checking if a user is still connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692069/signalr-checking-if-a-user-is-still-connected)

[2. Send message to specific user in SignalR](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/send-message-to-specific-user-in-signalr/)