# How to detect alive status of connection id signalr?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

There are many connectionIds
All of them are present in connectionMapping
What is the best way to check that the connectionId is still alive before sending the console?

Can't determine the cause of the problem

Comment: can [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692152) help you? Normally we can use `on disconnect` event to log a disconnected connection.