# OnConnected function won't fire in SignalR on Azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I'm making a chat app for my Azure website, developed in ASP.NET Web Forms, using SignalR.

For simplicity, I'll copy the two main C# files in question.

**ChatHub.cs**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    static List<Users> ConnectedUsers = new List<Users>();
    static List<Messages> CurrentMessage = new List<Messages>();

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
       
        if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
        {
            string logintime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ConnectedUsers.Add(new Users { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName, LoginTime = logintime });
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName, logintime);
        }
    }

    public void SendMessageToAll(string userName, string message, string time)
    {
        AddMessageinCache(userName, message, time);
        Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message, time);
    }

    private void AddMessageinCache(string userName, string message, string time)
    {
        CurrentMessage.Add(new Messages { UserName = userName, Message = message, Time = time });
        if (CurrentMessage.Count > 100)
            CurrentMessage.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);
            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(id, item.UserName);
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

**Chat.aspx (JavaScript)**

```
$(function() {
    var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
    registerClientMethods(chatHub);
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        registerEvents(chatHub);
    });

    function registerEvents(chatHub) {
        var name = '<%= this.UserName %>';   
        if (name.length > 0) {
            chatHub.server.connect(name);
        }
    }

    function registerClientMethods(chatHub) {
        chatHub.client.onConnected = function (id, userName, allUsers, messages, times) {
            console.log("Connected");
        }
        
        chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected = function (id, name, loginDate) {
            console.log("User Connected");
        }

        chatHub.client.onUserDisconnected = function (id, userName) {
            console.log("User Disconnected");
        }

        chatHub.client.messageReceived = function (userName, message, time) {
            console.log("Message Received");
        }
    }
});
```

None of the hub's client methods - except `messageReceived` - are triggered when necessary, evident by no `console.log()` messages appearing. The `Connect()` method is called by this line:

```
chatHub.server.connect(name);
```

And in the server-side, `OnConnected()` is called in `Connect()` here:

```
Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);
```

Thus, it should be firing the JavaScript function `chatHub.client.onConnected`, but doesn't.

Here is the network activity:

[image]

Note, the `negotiate`, `start` and `send` methods give 200 HTTP statuses immediately, but the `connect` method never completes.

I've tried adding subscriptions to the hub in the JS to force a connection, but that didn't work.

Comment: `static List<Users> ConnectedUsers = new List<Users>();` <-- this won't work, btw.

Comment: What do you see in your browser's DevTools > Network tab? Do you see any websocket or SSE connection attempts?

Comment: How/where are you registering `ChatHub`? Show us your OWIN `Startup` class/method.

Comment: @Dai See my edit. It's really interesting that the `connect` XHR request never completes/loads. Would you mind explaining why the static list won't work?

Comment: 1: Mutating a `static List<T>` without a `lock()` will corrupt the collection. 2: `static` objects aren't shared in a Web Garden nor Web Farm scenario. 3: state will be lost when IIS recycles your worker processes. 4: state will be cobbled when IIS runs two workers concurrently during windown+spinup. 5: See all of the highly-upvoted comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692069/signalr-checking-if-a-user-is-still-connected

Comment: Do you have WebSockets enabled in IIS? Are you running behind any load-balancer or firewall that interferes with WebSockets?

Comment: This is deployed to a Microsoft Azure server, but perhaps it is missing that setting.

Comment: WebSockets are not enabled by-default in Azure App Services. If you mean you've deployed it to a self-managed VM in Azure then there might be more hoops to jump through.

Comment: I just enabled WebSockets, but now the `connect` endpoint isn't even being called. Weird.

Comment: I was wondering if lists wouldn't be stateful. Storing messages and users in a database would probably be best, would you concur?

Comment: I can't really help you with the connection-level issues as I'd need to be there in-person with full access to everything to see where/what is misconfigured. As for keeping track of connected users: the trick is _you don't_ - instead you'd have "Ping" and "Pong" hub methods with each Pong receipt adding a new last-seen timestamp value in some shared persistent storage (i.e. not `static` state) and then determine who is "online" by some time cut-off, say, 15 seconds.

Comment: While I investigate the connection issue, what would you recommend for persistent storage? Maybe a logging library? If I use DB, I could use timestamps or a bit column if the user is online, updating on user connect and disconnect, although that would probably be overkill. Open for ideas.

Comment: In my own mini-chat feature (similar to yours) which also runs on Azure, I use Azure Storage Tables.

Comment: @Dai I finally figured out; in the end, enabling Web sockets was the real cure. It was reaching the /connect endpoint just fine, but there was a server-side error being thrown that wasn't being caught in my error logs, since it was running under a Web socket instead of HTTP. So, to catch the error message, I ran a .NET profiler trace in the Azure portal. I didn't include the faulty code in this post, so really if my server-side code had been error-free once you told me to enable Web sockets, the problem would have been solved right then and there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a rookie mistake here. The code would have worked just fine had I only enabled Web sockets in Azure. This web app is deployed to an Azure app service, and since SignalR utilizes Web sockets, they must be turned on, but Azure has them disabled by default. Simply log in to the Azure portal, go to your app service > Configuration > General Settings, and switch Web Sockets to "On".

**Note:** There was also a server-side error I generated in the `ChatHub.cs` file that I wasn't able to catch in my error logs, since SignalR is running over Web sockets instead of HTTP. To detect the error, you should run a .NET profiler trace in the Azure portal. To get there, click on your app service > Diagnose and solve problems > Diagnostic Tools > Collect .NET Profiler Trace. Start the trace and then reproduce the issue by triggering the calls to SignalR as the trace is being collected. This is important, or else you won't be able to gather the requests and any slowness, failures, or exceptions emanating from them.

So, if a SignalR method isn't being triggered on the client side and you think there is a server-side error, the best route to go for debugging is running a .NET profiler trace.